# Exclude post format from get_posts

Tags: get-posts, loop, post-formats, exclude

The title basically says it all.

I know I can use the following to get posts from the `aside` post format:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside' )
        )
    )
);

$asides = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $asides as $aside ) {
    setup_postdata( $aside );
    // HTML...
}
```

What I would like to know is **how do I get posts that are *not* in the `aside` post format**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the `operator` parameter to `'NOT IN'` ([see Codex on tax queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)).

Untested, but for your purposes:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. On a side note: I wish there were a simpler way to query post formats. Something like this: `'post-format' => array('aside')`.

Comment: Works perfectly